# Help with Windows Perfmon

Tags: windows-server-2008, perfmon

I want to understand how well Windows Server performs under certain application loads.

Generally I want  to check how CPU, memory, network and HDD are performing.
What counters should I check and what are the advisable values for those counters.

Answer (score 5):

The five counters I find most useful for these things are:

- CPU: *System\Processor Queue Length*. Divide the current queue length by the number of CPU cores in the system. If the result is less than 10, your CPU is in good shape - even if it is running at 100%. Though at 100%, it wouldn't take much *more* load to swamp the system.
- Memory: *Memory\Pages Input/Sec*. This shows how often the system has to read things from disk (a file, or virtual memory) that it wanted to have ready in RAM. Now, many things first *get* to RAM by being read from disk, so some spikes are common. But if the system isn't doing a lot of work that naturally reads constantly from disk, these spikes should be short, and the counter should regularly return to zero.
- Network Input: *Network Interface\Packets Received Errors\NIC name*. If you're seeing more than the occasional error, you should be looking for problems in your NICs, your switches, or your wiring.
- Network Output: *Network Interface\Output Queue Length\NIC name*. The number of packets waiting to be sent. If this consistently goes above 2, you have a network bottleneck and should be looking to resolve network issues or add bandwidth.
- Disk Utilization: *PhysicalDisk\Current Disk Queue Length\driveletter*. Divide this by the number of spindles you have. If the resulting number is higher than 3 (and stays that way for long periods), something is asking for data faster than the disk (or array) can provide it. Consider lowering demand on the disk, or getting a faster disk system. I saved disk for last because it is the most common sign of a bottleneck. Sometimes a high disk queue length is really a sign of a memory shortage - you'll see Pages Input/Sec go way up, too.

For more detail, see my article: [Windows Perfmon: The Top Ten Counters](http://itcookbook.net/blog/windows-perfmon-top-ten-counters)